# PyDev: Python: Unresolved Import or ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, pydev

tl;dr How should I correctly use relative modules in PyDev?

If I use:
`from . import myModule`
I get the following error:
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

However...
If I just use:
`import myModule`
the project will run, but PyDev flags the line and file with
`Unresolved Import: myModule`

The package has an `__init__.py` although its contents are empty

Edit: screenshot of PyDev Explorer structure added as requested by @Fabio Zadrozny

[PyDev Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpYMy.png)

Comment: It'd be interesting if you can post a screenshot of your `PyDev package explorer` showing the structure of your project to be able to diagnose the issue (it's hard to give any hints without knowing the structure you're using...).

Comment: @FabioZadrozny screenshot added to OP as requested.

Comment: thanks @FabioZadrozny your reply has indeed solved the issue.  Cheers Stamper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it depends on how you run the script... by default PyDev will run the file directly, but in this case you want to run the file with `-m <module-name>`.

PyDev can do that automatically if you go to `PyDev > Run` and enable the related setting:

[image: Setting to run with -m]

p.s.: either you have to use the relative import and launch with `-m` or you can just use the full import (which in this particular case would be `from pkg_BootMeUPY import in_constrains_ini as const` -- in which case it'd work regardless of how you launch the file).